# Caffe compiled fine with cudnn however runtest fails with error: CUDNN_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH

Tags: compilation, cuda, automated-tests, caffe

When running make runtest using caffe I get the following output, it all compiles fine with Cudnn no errors are provided, I have also included the output of build_release/tools/caffe device_query -gpu <0,1> for both NVidia Tesla GPUs running Cuda driver and runtime version 7.0. Could anyone help?

```
[----------] 1 test from SolverTest/0, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<float>
[ RUN      ] SolverTest/0.TestInitTrainTestNets
F0907 18:53:28.279698   309 cudnn_softmax_layer.cpp:19] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (6 vs. 0)  CUDNN_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x2b8a426cfdaa  (unknown)
    @     0x2b8a426cfce4  (unknown)
    @     0x2b8a426cf6e6  (unknown)
    @     0x2b8a426d2687  (unknown)
    @     0x2b8a4404b3c5  caffe::CuDNNSoftmaxLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x2b8a440bf8a7  caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @     0x2b8a440eb9dd  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x2b8a440eca25  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x2b8a4410335a  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x2b8a44104354  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x2b8a44104659  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x787e9c  caffe::SolverTest<>::InitSolverFromProtoString()
    @           0x785170  caffe::SolverTest_TestInitTrainTestNets_Test<>::TestBody()
    @           0x7e9943  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x7e0627  testing::Test::Run()
    @           0x7e06ce  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x7e07d5  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x7e3b18  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x7e3da7  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x45552a  main
    @     0x2b8a44d70ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x45bd69  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
make: *** [runtest] Aborted (core dumped)


% ./build_release/tools/caffe device_query -gpu 0
I0907 18:55:04.830653   729 caffe.cpp:111] Querying GPUs 0
I0907 18:55:05.037142   729 common.cpp:168] Device id:                     0
I0907 18:55:05.037195   729 common.cpp:169] Major revision number:         2
I0907 18:55:05.037201   729 common.cpp:170] Minor revision number:         0
I0907 18:55:05.037207   729 common.cpp:171] Name:                          Tesla M2090
I0907 18:55:05.037214   729 common.cpp:172] Total global memory:           5636554752
I0907 18:55:05.037220   729 common.cpp:173] Total shared memory per block: 49152
I0907 18:55:05.037225   729 common.cpp:174] Total registers per block:     32768
I0907 18:55:05.037231   729 common.cpp:175] Warp size:                     32
I0907 18:55:05.037236   729 common.cpp:176] Maximum memory pitch:          2147483647
I0907 18:55:05.037241   729 common.cpp:177] Maximum threads per block:     1024
I0907 18:55:05.037246   729 common.cpp:178] Maximum dimension of block:    1024, 1024, 64
I0907 18:55:05.037253   729 common.cpp:181] Maximum dimension of grid:     65535, 65535, 65535
I0907 18:55:05.037258   729 common.cpp:184] Clock rate:                    1301000
I0907 18:55:05.037263   729 common.cpp:185] Total constant memory:         65536
I0907 18:55:05.037268   729 common.cpp:186] Texture alignment:             512
I0907 18:55:05.037272   729 common.cpp:187] Concurrent copy and execution: Yes
I0907 18:55:05.037278   729 common.cpp:189] Number of multiprocessors:     16
I0907 18:55:05.037283   729 common.cpp:190] Kernel execution timeout:      No


% ./build_release/tools/caffe device_query -gpu 1
I0907 18:55:15.162884   784 caffe.cpp:111] Querying GPUs 1
I0907 18:55:20.532964   784 common.cpp:168] Device id:                     1
I0907 18:55:20.533093   784 common.cpp:169] Major revision number:         2
I0907 18:55:20.533129   784 common.cpp:170] Minor revision number:         0
I0907 18:55:20.533161   784 common.cpp:171] Name:                          Tesla M2090
I0907 18:55:20.533193   784 common.cpp:172] Total global memory:           5636554752
I0907 18:55:20.533227   784 common.cpp:173] Total shared memory per block: 49152
I0907 18:55:20.533252   784 common.cpp:174] Total registers per block:     32768
I0907 18:55:20.533277   784 common.cpp:175] Warp size:                     32
I0907 18:55:20.533298   784 common.cpp:176] Maximum memory pitch:          2147483647
I0907 18:55:20.533323   784 common.cpp:177] Maximum threads per block:     1024
I0907 18:55:20.533345   784 common.cpp:178] Maximum dimension of block:    1024, 1024, 64
I0907 18:55:20.533371   784 common.cpp:181] Maximum dimension of grid:     65535, 65535, 65535
I0907 18:55:20.533404   784 common.cpp:184] Clock rate:                    1301000
I0907 18:55:20.533428   784 common.cpp:185] Total constant memory:         65536
I0907 18:55:20.533452   784 common.cpp:186] Texture alignment:             512
I0907 18:55:20.533476   784 common.cpp:187] Concurrent copy and execution: Yes
I0907 18:55:20.533500   784 common.cpp:189] Number of multiprocessors:     16
I0907 18:55:20.533524   784 common.cpp:190] Kernel execution timeout:      No
```

Comment: Your GPU isn't supported by cudnn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cuDNN library [requires a GPU of compute capability 3.0 or higher](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn):

> Supported on Windows, Linux and MacOS systems with Kepler, Maxwell or Tegra K1 GPUs.

Your Fermi M2090 is a compute capability 2.0 GPU:

```
I0907 18:55:05.037195   729 common.cpp:169] Major revision number:         2
I0907 18:55:05.037201   729 common.cpp:170] Minor revision number:         0
I0907 18:55:05.037207   729 common.cpp:171] Name:                          Tesla M2090
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have breezed over that bit. I guess I can still run caffe on the GPU just not with the cudnn improvements. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think you can configure caffe to not use cuDNN.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check type this command `nvidia-smi` using  the terminal.
Then go to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and try to find your GPU in the table. You will probably find out that your gpu have lower compute capability than 3.0 which is not supported for cuDNN.

Based on your output and TESLA M2090 you probably have one of the following GPUs:

> GeForce GTX 590, GeForce GTX 580, GeForce GTX 570, GeForce GTX 480,
>   GeForce GTX 470, GeForce GTX 465, GeForce GTX 480M

And  the compute capability of above GPUs is 2.0. So my suggestion is  try to install caffe without cuDNN , and do not use it at least in current machine.